# Injection from $\mathbb{N} \to F$ an ordered field?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be an ordered field. Is it necessarily true that there is an injection $f:\mathbb{N} \to F$? If that is the case, then I suppose from there it can be concluded that $F$ must be an infinite set. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is an ordered field, then the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb N&\longrightarrow&F\\&n&\mapsto&\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\text{ times}}\end{array}$$is an injective map. So, yes, $F$ is infinite.

Comment: doesn't your answer imply $f(n)=n$?

Comment: If $n\in\mathbb N$, how do you see $n$ as an element of $F$? If you see it as $\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\text{ times}}$, then the answer is affirmative.

Comment: I think I am getting confused here. Then in this case, how are additive inverses of $F$ being constructed? If we take $f(n)=n$ then there is no element such that $n + (-n) = 0$, in which case $F$ is not a field. I feel I am missing something here.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing that all that I claimed is that $f$ is injective. I never claimed that $f(\mathbbb{N})=F$ (which is good, since they are **not** equal).

Comment: I think that might be it. So just to clarify, there might be elements in $F$ that might not be captured by $f(\mathbb{N})$. Is that correct?

Comment: It's more than that: there **is** some element of $F$ that doesn't belong to $f(\mathbb{N})$: $-1$, for instance.

Comment: Yes got it! Thanks!

Comment: Or, you could extend $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ and it would be a homomorphism.  Injective but still not necessarily surjective.

Comment: Every ordered field contains an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb Q$, proceeding in this way..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true - take $1, 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 1, \dots$.

Indeed, addition obeys the order, so this must be a strictly increasing sequence; trichotomy then guarantees that none of these are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be an ordered field. By recursion define $f: \mathbb{N} \to F$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(n+1)= f(n)+1$, where the $+$ is taken in $\mathbb{N}$ for $n+1$ and as the $+$-operation in $F$ in $f(n)+1$ (if you want to be ultraprecise, distinguish them by notation, like $+_F$ etc.)

Then $f(1)=1$ and the axioms for an ordered field tell us that $0=f(0)<_F 1=f(1)$.
Also, if $f(m) < f(n)$ for all $m < n$ then for $m < n+1$ we have $m < n$ and $f(m) <_F f(n) <_F f(n)+1=f(n+1)$, or $m=n$ and then also $f(m)=f(n) <_F f(n)+1=f(n+1)$. So by induction we have shown that $m < n$ implies $f(m) <_F f(n)$ and so we have an order-preserving injection from $\mathbb{N}$ into $F$.
In particular, $F$ is infinite.